# Good on-screen ruler application for Windows?

Tags: windows, ruler

What's a good (preferably free) on-screen ruler for Windows? I just need to measure a few things in pixels on the screen. I need it to be flexible (easily resizable and able to measure both vertically and horizontally), and hopefully not [look like crap](http://www.spadixbd.com/freetools/jruler.htm). A quick Google search revealed a ton of different applications, and I don't want to try every single one.

Comment: I used JR Screen ruler for ages, and just realised there are better alternatives.  Thanks for the question.

Comment: You could also try http://www.markus-bader.de/MB-Ruler/download.php

Comment: Yet another option would be https://github.com/bluegrams/ScreenRuler

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/screenruler/ this one works well with a UHD 4K monitor

Answer (score 118, accepted):

I have been using Ruler from Codeplex for ages now (I removed the old link because it was considered harmful by Chrome). Very easy to use, a simple program with simple options:

- Always on top
- The vertical and horizontal measurement
- Option to show ToolTip for smaller dimensions.
- Resizable by dragging
- Can open multiple instances
- No installation required

Forked and improved on GitHub and [enhanced](https://github.com/andrijac/ruler/blob/master/NewFeatures.md) https://github.com/andrijac/ruler

Comment: Ah yeah, I forgot to mention transparency :) np.

Comment: hmm.. only pixels, can't change units of measurement. No free rotate. Looks great, but I can't use it.

Comment: I have forked the code from codeplex to github https://github.com/andrijac/ruler

Comment: This app is buggy because if you move it around quickly it handles the mouse events erroneously and either "lets go" or starts resizing itself. Aggravating! Otherwise very neat. Due to this, JR ruler is more functional

Comment: @StevenLu Resize-while-moving-the-ruler is exactly one of the reasons I have forked the project on github and added Lock feature https://github.com/andrijac/ruler :) HTH

Comment: Oh that's brilliant. Yes I do like this one because it has transparency and is not bright yellow. Though, now that i test it, you didn't actually fix the root bug, you just made a workaround to lock the size...it helps but the bug is still present, most noticeably where if you drag it from a spot near the edge, if you go fast in that direction, it will simply "drop" it. While it is an improvement in a certain sense it does require an extra step to lock after editing the size...

Comment: Awesome. Just one exe, no install and special priviledges required.
I was using another ruler before of which I forgot the name. But I think this one is better.

Comment: I just visited the URL for [Ruler](http://ruler.codeplex.com/). The Chrome browser gave me a scary warning: "The site ahead contains harmful programs
Attackers on archive.codeplex.com might attempt to trick you into installing programs that harm your browsing experience (for example, by changing your homepage or showing extra ads on sites you visit).". I have no further information about the site.

Comment: @KeithThompson you are right, seems like Codeplex is considered harmful. I'll strike out the link.

Answer (score 25):

I recommend using [PicPick](http://picpick.wiziple.net/).

It has a ruler (horizontal or vertical) with custom units, but also others very usefull tools like screencapture, colorpicker, magnifier, angular ruler and other tools.

Comment: I don't see how you can change units on the ruler..

Comment: Got it: (long) right click on the ruler - then when you release the mouse button you see the context menu with units on it.

Comment: I had this installed and didn't realize it had all these other awesome features.

Comment: I also had PicPick installed and didn't know it has a ruler. What a lifesaver, thanks!

Answer (score 17):

I really like A Ruler for Windows (freeware) - why, well I wrote it! ;-)

Seriously, it: measures pixels,
horizontal / vertical,
maginifies your primary screen under the ruler up to 4x,
has an automatic center line (which you can toggle on and off), allows you to 
put ticks on either long edge, you can resize by it dragging an end,
comes with four skins (woodgrain, stainless steel, clear plastic see thru, yellow construction) and you can add your own skins,
works across multiple screens.

Enjoy!

[www.arulerforwindows.com](http://www.arulerforwindows.com)

Comment: I meant to add this comment a million years ago, but I forgot. The lack of a rotation feature makes the ruler a lot less useful than it could be. Even in 2010, it needed that feature, but I can't recommend the app to anyone in 2020 now that so many other rulers exist with a rotate feature.

Comment: FWIW the tool now has a rotate option, but the magnify option is broken (you can magnify, but not de-magnify unless the entire ruler is visible (so if longer than your screen-resolution it won't allow changing), requiring an Alt+F4 to close out the application.

Comment: just to clarify, the program has always been able to rotate between vertical and horizontal, it just can't rotate in between (for example 30 degrees).  To demagnify if the ruler is off the screen you don't need to Alt+F4 (which will end the program), rather just press the escape key and the magnification will be canceled.

Answer (score 6):

I just use Paint.

When you move the mouse around, it displays the pixes of wherever the mouse is on the status bar, even if it's not in the foreground. With a 2000x2000 image you can resize the window to any shape.

Comment: This unfortunately appears not to work with Windows 7.

Comment: Also does not appear to work with Windows 10

Comment: @OskarAustegard It's still working for me on Windows 10. The status bar can be hidden, so make sure that's visible under View -> Status bar.

Comment: +1 still works on win10.  Plus the 2nd section will show the X / Y of the last click/drag, so use the rec select or draw a line and you can get the pixel distance of horizontal and vertical.  Combine with Win+Shift+S to take quick screenshots if you can't install things on a lockeddown machine